# Display product image, specs and price from SQL database when user selects product in drop-down list using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am a newbie and working on a school project and I am creating a IT order form.  I am trying to find out the best way that when the user selects a product from the product drop-down list, the product's image, specs and price will pull from the SQL server database and display on the form.  I am coding in asp.net and C# and SQL server is my database.

Comment: You should start by writing some code.

Comment: More specifically, what is the best data control to use to display one table row at a time?  That is what I am trying to figure out.